# Combining Metrics with different labels for Alerts

Tags: prometheus

So here is my Intention:
I have a Node exporter on every Server with supplies me with a Up metric, the thing is only because the exporter ist down, it doesn't mean that the Server is down. So additionally use the Blackbox exporter to and Check if the server is reachable via icmp. Now I want to combine both of the Metrics to a alert, because if the Server is Not reachable via Ping and the exporter is down, chances are high the server is actually down.

Here is my Query:

```
Instance:Up == 0 and ON(instance) instance:probe_success == 0
```

The Problem is that the instance Labels are slightly different:
The Node exporter Runs on Port 10500, which leads to the Label my.instance.com:10500 while icmp does not use the port so my.instance.com.

Is there a way to combine these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`label_replace`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace) to replace the `instance` label (or add some other label) with the hostname only from the `"hostname:port"` value in `instance`.

Something along the lines of:

```
up{job="node"}
  or on(instance)
label_replace(probe_success{job="prober"}, "instance", "$1", "instance", "(.+):.+"
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right documentation Spot! I solved this by adding the Port to the Probe-metric with the "$0:10500" replacement and just matched the whole instance with .*